Axiomatization of hyperreal numbers
From wikipedia:

The hyperreals can be developed either axiomatically or by more constructively oriented methods. The essence of the axiomatic approach is to assert (1) the existence of at least one infinitesimal number, and (2) the validity of the transfer principle. In the following subsection we give a detailed outline of a more constructive approach.

I know how to assert (1) as a first-order axiom, but I don't know how to assert (2) as a first-order axiom because the descriptions of the transfer principle that I have at hand are usually imprecise. My understanding is that the transfer principle is essentially Los's theorem.
Is there an axiomatization of hyperreal numbers?
Such axiomatization would allow me to answer the question of uniqueness of the system. I know that when using the ultrapower construction, uniqueness depends on the continuous hypothesis, but is this true in general?

See axiom (T) in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internal_set_theory
